# Integral curves of a vector field not tangent to an embedded submanifold $S$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

I got stuck on a problem. Let $M$ be a smooth $n-$dimensional manifold and let $S$ be a compact embedded submanifold. Suppose $V$ is nowhere tangent to $S.$ Prove that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that the flow of $V$ restrict to a smooth embedding
$$\Phi:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times S \to M.$$ Firstly, by the compactness of $S,$ we find a positive $\epsilon>0$ for which all the integral curves with initial conditions in $S$ are defined on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon).$ The differential of $\Phi$ if I am not mistaken should be of this form: $$(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, di_{S}),$$ where $i_{S}$ is the inclusion of $S$ in $M,$ practically by definition this should have maximum rank.
The only part I'm not sure is on how to prove that $\Phi$ is open.
Since $S$ is embedded for every point $y \in S$ there is a chart $(U,\varphi)$ in $M$ in which $U\cap S$ is diffeomorphic under $\varphi$ to a set of the form
$$\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N} : (x^1,\dots,x^{k},\,0, \dots,\,0) \}.$$ Since $V$ is nowhere tangent to $S$ it's not restrictive to suppose the differential of $\varphi$ sends $V$ to the constant vector field $e_{k+1}.$ So the integral curves with initial conditions on $S$ should all be of the form
$$\gamma(t)=(x^1,\dots,x^{k},t,\dots,0).$$ So the set $\Phi(S\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon))$ is diffeomorphic to the following relative open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$
$$ \{(x^1,\dots,x^{k},t,\dots,0): ((x^1,\dots,x^{k}) \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}, \, t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \},$$ so the map $\Phi$ is open on is image and we are done.
Is this reasoning correct? Where should I be more precise?

Comment: What is the meaning of your title? What does it have to do with the actual issues?

Comment: Sorry, @TedShifrin maybe the title is too short, because I only specified the domain of the application $\Phi$. When I wrote the post, it seemed a good title. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: I think it's a language issue. I think we would say integral curves of a vector field. Flux refers to an integral over a hypersurface (like the flux of the electric or magnetic field).

Comment: @TedShrifrin I thought integral flux was a used term. I didn’t thought of that. I got confused with the Italian term ‘flusso integrale’! https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flusso#:~:text=Il%20flusso%20di%20un%20campo,su%20tutta%20la%20superficie%20stessa. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's the notion of flux, but that's not what you're really doing here. You're finding integral curves flowing by the vector field, not finding flux across the surface.

Comment: @TedShifrin I confused the two terms integral flow and integral flux because in my language flux and flow are synonyms! I didn't realize it.

Comment: @TedShifrin just to be sure, what's the name of the application which brings the couple $(t,x_0)$ to the point $\gamma(t)$ where $\gamma$ it's the integral curve which has $x_0$ as the initial data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133246/discussion-between-matteo-aldovardi-and-ted-shifrin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a bit more.

Let $F: M\times {\mathbb R}\to M$ be the (partially defined) flow of the vector field $V$. By compactness of $S$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that you have a well-defined map
$$
\Phi: S\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M, \Phi(x,t)=F(x,t), x\in S.
$$
As you correctly noted, the map $\Phi$ is an immersion at each point of $S\times \{0\}$. Hence, taking $\epsilon>0$ small enough, you get that $\Phi$ is an immersion. [Indeed, immersion means injectivity of the derivative. But if the derivative is injective at one point, then it is also injective at all nearby points. Compactness of $S$ then implies the existence of $\epsilon>0$ such that $\Phi$ defined above is an immersion.]

Thus, for each $x\in S$ there exists $\epsilon_x\in (0,\epsilon)$ an a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $S$ such that the restriction
$$
\Phi: U_x\times (-\epsilon_x, \epsilon_x)\to M
$$
is 1-1. Since $\Phi$ restrict to the (identity) embedding on $S\times \{0\}$, for each pair $(x,y)\in S\times S$ there exists $\epsilon_{xy}\in (0,\epsilon)$ and a product neighborhood $U_{x,y}\times U_{y,x}$ of $(x,y)$ in $S\times S$ such that the restriction
$$
\Phi: (U_{x,y}\cup U_{y,x})\times (-\epsilon_{xy}, \epsilon_{xy})\to M
$$
is 1-1. [Indeed, the fact that $\Phi$ is an immersion implies that for each $x\in S$ there exists a product neighborhood $U_x\times (-\epsilon_x, \epsilon_y)$ of $(x,0)$ such that $\Phi$ restricted to this neighborhood is an embedding. Now, if $x=y$ then we can take $U_{x,y}= U_{y,x}=U_x$ and $\epsilon_{xy}=\epsilon_x$. Suppose that $x\ne y$. Then, after shrinking $U_x, U_y$ if necessary, we can find disjoint neighborhoods $V_x, V_y$ of $x, y$ in $M$ and $\epsilon_{xy}>0$ such that
$$
\Phi(U_x\times (-\epsilon_{xy}, \epsilon_{xy}))\subset V_x,$$
$$
\Phi(U_y\times (-\epsilon_{xy}, \epsilon_{xy}))\subset V_y.$$
This is a direct consequence of the fact that $\Phi$ restricted to $S$ is the identity map. Lastly, injectivity of $\Phi$ on each $U_x\times (-\epsilon_{xy},\epsilon_{xy})$, $U_y\times (-\epsilon_{xy}, \epsilon_{xy})$ implies the claimed injectivity of $\Phi$ on the union of these two open subsets. Hence, we can take
$$
U_{xy}=U_x, U_{y,x}=U_y,
$$
thereby proving the claim.]

By compactness of $S$, we can find a finite subcover of $S\times S$ by these product neighborhoods. Hence, there exists $\delta\in (0,\epsilon)$ such that
$$
\Phi: S\times (-\delta,\delta)\to M
$$
is 1-1. Since $S\times  [-\delta/2,\delta/2]$ is compact and $M$ is Hausdorff, the injective continuous map
$$
\Phi: S\times [-\delta/2,\delta/2]\to M
$$
is a homeomorphism to its image. Thus, the restriction
$$
\Phi: S\times (-\delta/2,\delta/2)\to M
$$
is an immersion and a homeomorphism to its image, hence, an (smooth) embedding. qed

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been outstandingly clear!

Comment: @MatteoAldovardi: By the way, a better terminology would be to say that the flow (or a vector field) is **normal** to a submanifold. One can also say "nowhere tangent" but it is a bit heavy.

Comment: thanks, I will keep it in mind!

Comment: Hello Moishe I have some questions about your answer. Why is $\Phi$ an immersion for $\epsilon$ small enough since $\Phi$ is an immersion at each point of $S \times \{0\}$? Does this follow from $S$ being compact? Also, how do we get a pair $U_{x,y}, U_{y,x}$ and $\epsilon_{xy}$ such that $\Phi:(U_{x,y} \cup U_{y,x})\times (-\epsilon_{xy}, \epsilon_{xy}) \to M$ is 1-1 from the fact that $\Phi$is an embedding on $S \times \{0\}$? I'm not sure why you need to consider these product neighborhoods instead of just covering with $U_x$ constructed prior.

Comment: Also how do we know that $\Phi$ will be 1-1 on the union of the covers?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician: I can add more details explaining all these, but how familiar are you with immersion? Do you know the definition and basic properties?

Comment: @MoisheKohan This problem is from the book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John Lee. I'm familiar with the properties of immersions and embeddings given in the book. I think you are using the facts that if $F:M \to N$ is a smooth map and $p \in M$ and $df_p$ is injective then $p$ has a neighborhood $U$: $F|_U$ is an immersion. And the rank theorem to show that there is a neighborhood in which $F$ is 1-1 if $F$ is an immersion.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Hello Moishe could you please explain to me with more details? I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician: OK, later....

Comment: @nomadicmathematician: Done.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician: Think about the definition of continuity at a point.